# Date.getDate always return 1

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

For an unknown reason, `getDate` always return `1` instead of `28`. I'm using NodeJS 10.6.0 and Typescript 3.2.2.

```js
const lastDay = new Date();
lastDay.setDate(0);
lastDay.setHours(24, 59, 59, 999);
console.log(lastDay, "|", lastDay.getDate()); // 2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z | 1
```

**Edit:** I'm trying to get the last day of the previous month at the last ms. Then `setDate(0)` is correct. What i don't understand exactly is, why when i print the time i get `28T23:59:59.999Z` and `getDate()` returns the next day.

**Edit2:** Effectively using `getUTCDate` fix my issue, it remain weird to me due to the strange way it's implemented. IMO each methods should be more explicitely named to avoid this kind of issue.

Comment: Well, it's past 24:00, so it's the 1st. The date you get printed is in UTC

Comment: Did you mean to put `23`?

Comment: "*Effectively using `getUTCDate` fix my issue*" the entire issue is that you are setting the hour to past `24:00`. Whatever the day is, the 24th hour of it is the *next* day.  If you only want to get the last date, of the previous month, then you either don't need to `setHours` at all or don't set them to more than 24 hours. That's it. You get `2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z` printed because that's the UTC time. You *were* in a +1 zone at the 28th, so the *local* time is `2019-03-01T00:59:59.999 +01:00` which is exactly what you set it to 24 hours 59 minutes on the 28th is 00:59 on the 1st

Comment: Maybe i'll have to use Date.UTC instead of date constructor to avoid mistake

Answer (score 1):

It's actually correct:

> `Date.prototype.getDate()`
>
> Returns the day of the month (1-31) for the specified date according to local time.

You can test it so:

```
const lastDay: Date = new Date();
lastDay.setDate(3);
lastDay.setHours(24, 59, 59, 999);
console.log(lastDay, "|", lastDay.getDate()); // 2019-03-03T23:59:59.999Z | 4
```

Comment: No, he's trying to set a date in the previous month, which is why the code calls `setDate(0)`.

Comment: But hisLast day variable logs 28 as a day 2019-02-28

Comment: @Pointy but then setting the hours to a full day ahead. So it's still the 1st.

Comment: @VLAZ yes exactly, that's the real problem.

Comment: @Andam the 28th *in UTC* `getDate` gives you local time, so adjusted for the timezone

Comment: @VLAZ yea this with combination seting last minute

Comment: @Andam the OP is probably one hour ahead of UTC.

Comment: I expect to get the last day of the previous month, this is why i'm doing `setDate(0)`

Comment: Edit your answer to include timezone difference

Comment: @Gecko but then you are adding a full day on top of that last day making it roll over.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the hours, you're passing 24 instead of 23.

Also, when you print the date, you might want to use `.toLocaleString()` so that you get the local time instead of UTC.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why you'd set the hours to 23:59, either. It seems to be what OP was actually meaning to use and it avoids the day rolling over, but it's an odd time to set.

Comment: I suspect the intention was to get the "last moment" of the previous month, possibly for some sort of filtering or a query predicate. I'd use the 1st of the next month at 00:00:00.0000 and use `<` :)

Comment: @Pointy you're right, i'm getting the really last moment of the previous month. I'd prefer to use the exact value i need insetad of an higher value and doing a useless operation on it, but your idea is pretty good for less strict context :)

Comment: @Gecko the last moment of the last month occurs at **23**:59, not *an hour later*.

Comment: @Gecko you could set the date to the 1st of the current month, at 00:00:00.0000, and then set the milliseconds to -1.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing its job as advertised.

```
lastDay.setDate(0);
```

set the day to the last of the relative month. then you add a full day with 24+ so it's the first day of the next month.

Answer (score 0):

thats happening because you are setting the hours as well, remove the line of code where you are setting the hours and you will get the expected result:-

```
const lastDay = new Date();
lastDay.setDate(0);
//lastDay.setHours(24, 59, 59, 999);
console.log(lastDay, "|", lastDay.getDate()); //Thu Feb 28 2019 19:01:20 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time) "|" 28
```